# Alert dialog hides after startActivityForResult

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have a main activity that starts an alert dialog, in the alert dialog I have a button that starts another activity to select a file, after the file is selected and file selector activity hides, the original alert dialog hides as well so the user can't actually click the OK button of the alert dialog. Any idea why this is happening?

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        if(v.getId() == R.id.zoneImageContainer)
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.zone_menu, menu);
        else if(v instanceof RadioButton)
        {
            menuRadio = (RadioButton)v;
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.key_menu, menu);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.editZoneMenuItem:
                showEditZoneDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.newZoneMenuItem:
                break;
            case R.id.deleteZoneMenuItem:
                break;

            case R.id.editKeyMenuItem:
                showEditKeyDialog(menuRadio);
                break;
            case R.id.newKeyMenuItem:
                showNewKeyDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.deleteKeyMenuItem:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void showEditZoneDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Zone Details:");
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_zone_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        final Button houseAddressButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.housePickerButton);
        final EditText nameText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        final TextView addressText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.addressTextView);

    .
    .
    .

        houseAddressButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
        .
        .
        .
            }
        });

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FileDialog.class);
                intent.putExtra(FileDialog.START_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                intent.putExtra(FileDialog.CAN_SELECT_DIR, false);
                intent.putExtra(FileDialog.SELECTION_MODE, SelectionMode.MODE_OPEN);
                intent.putExtra(FileDialog.FORMAT_FILTER,
                        new String[] { "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "gif" });
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });

        // Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        .
        .
        .
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: @gunar I was not asking about dialog size...

Comment: @FarzadBekran: wrong question for me ... I had them in separated tabs and messed them in the end

Comment: The alert dialog is a dialog or is it wrapped in a `DialogFragment`?

Comment: @gunar check the code please I don't really understand what you mean by that.

Comment: It will hide because this is a nature of Alert dialogs. If you want to have it back once selector Activity hides use FragmentDialog instead.

Comment: Don't you get WindowLeakedExceptions in the stack trace? The app doesn't get killed but the Logcat is flooded with these traces ... maybe?

Comment: You need to change all your dialogs from simple dialogs to DialogFragments. In this way the fragment manager will know to recreate one if you're changing the orientation or getting back

Comment: @gunar with DialogFragments, still not working